# vc++ (sqlite)how to distingush statement is SELECT - or NOT?

Tags: c++, sqlite, select

My code is necessary to distinguish whether Sql statement is SELECT or not.

If the result is more than 1, it is easy to distinguish select.
But there is no result when the statement executed, how do I distinguish it?

```
sqlite_stmt *some_stmt;
//case 1 : (the table has no row)
  sqlite3_prepare("select * from some_table", &some_stmt);
//case 2 :
  sqlite3_prepare("create table some_table2", &some_stmt);
  int result = sqlite3_step(some_stmt);
```

result is same :

```
SQLITE_DONE;
```

I can distinguish it with two method,
1st is get substring from the statement. but i don't want do it, it seems to be incorrectly way.
2st is use `sqlite3_column_count()`. Usually column_count has one or more than if the statement is SELECT.

Is it correct way using `sqlite3_coulmn_count()`? Isn't there anything that No-column-table in sqlite or etc?

I want correct way to distinguish whether Statement is SELECT or Not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other statements that return data (e.g., some PRAGMAs), so you cannot search for "SELECT".

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_count.html), `sqlite3_column_count()` is the correct way:

> This routine returns 0 if pStmt is an SQL statement that does not return data (for example an UPDATE).

In SQL, there is no such thing as a table without columns. Even in a construct that does not actually look at any data (such as `EXISTS (SELECT ...)`), you have to use some dummy column(s).

Comment: Thank's a lot! I want conviction that there isn't no-column_table. I can do my project without any worry :)